# How to grid expand resize windows dynamically?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to dynamically grid adjust with resize?

in this site https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html, it explains by default each column have 0 weight. it means no expand.

i just set as the site tells. the ratio is 1:2. each pixel label resize = 2 pixel username entry.

but it stay with same size

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
root.geometry("100x50")
loginFrame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="red")

userLabel = tkinter.Label(loginFrame, text="Username")
userEntry = tkinter.Entry(loginFrame)


userLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky= tkinter.W)
userEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky= tkinter.E)

loginFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
loginFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
loginFrame.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ask yoursel fthis: is the problem that the entry isn't resizing in the frame, or is it the frame that isn't resizing in the root window?

Comment: @BryanOakley If so how to set loginFrame to expand automatically?

i set `loginFrame.grid(column=0, row=0)`. i hope it fill and expand as root resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` to the `root` window.

Then apply them to your `loginFrame`.

Changing `sticky` will radically alter the behaviour of `userLabel` and `userEntry`.

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
root.geometry("100x50")

# apply to root is essential
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

loginFrame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="red")
loginFrame.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky = tkinter.NSEW)

# now apply to loginFrame
loginFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
loginFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
loginFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 2)

userLabel = tkinter.Label(loginFrame, text="Username")
userEntry = tkinter.Entry(loginFrame)

# experiment by changing sticky 
if False:
    # expand userLabel and userEntry to fill entire loginFrame
    s = tkinter.NSEW
else:
    # confine userLabel and userEntry to change in width only
    s = tkinter.EW

userLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky= s)
userEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky= s)

root.mainloop()
```